# How to customize Overlay Xamarin Labs Mediapicker?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I need to draw graphics and text over the camera stream video.
I'm using Xamarin Labs Mediapicker.

I read on an other post to register my own MediaPicker.cs to implement a custom renderer. How can I do that ?

For the moment, I need it on iOS.

Thancks by advance for your help !